# Appending into @section

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4 and I'd like to extend what's already placed in my master.blade.php template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    @section('head')
        @parent
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>{{$title}}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{{$description}}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/main.css') }}">
    @show
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```

For example, my home.blade.php template:

```
@section('head');
appending to head....
@show

@section('content')
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
@show
```

So I was trying to append "appending to head..." into the template. But it just replaces what's already there. With some research I came to an conclusion that it's not possible, but I'm not sure how else would I do this.. Partials? Includes?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in the home.blade.php template that extends the master.blade.php:

this could be your home.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('head')
  @parent 
  {{{ $head_data }}}
@stop

{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')
  Here comes you content...
@stop
```

You can call it from your controller

```
<?php

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function getIndex()
  {

    $head_data = 'appending to head....';

    return View::make('home', compact('head_data'));
  }

}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned I am using controller layouts.